# VueJS Router-View e Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetable

Eu tenho uma página com 2 estruturas usando router-view. **Menu** e **Content**. o no meu **Menu** eu tenho uma página chamada "**Lojas**", nessa página "**Lojas**" possui uma tabela, eu dou um Axios.Get na minha API e ela me retornar um JSON que joga pra tabela de "**Lojas**".

**Problema:** Se minha API tem um dado novo, eu tenho que recarregar a view.

**Solução que gostaria**: Quando eu clicar lá no menu no item "**Lojas**", eu queria que a view atual (no caso "**Lojas**") recarregasse para que o Axios desse o Get de novo e a Tabela trouxesse os dados atuais.

@EDIT

**Lojas.vue**

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" id="dataTable" width="100%">
       <tbody class="animated fadeIn">
          <tr v-for="item in dataItem" v-bind:key="item.Id">
             <td class="text-left">{{item.Name}}</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            dataItem: [],
            errors: []
         }),
        created() {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8090/API/Lojas`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.dataItem = response.data.Data
                }).then(() => {
                    $('#dataTable').DataTable( datatableConfigBR )
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    this.errors.push(e)
                })
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Menu.vue**

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
   <li>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'lojas' }">Lojas</router-link>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**routes.js**

```
import lojas from './Lojas.vue'

const routes = [{
        path: '/Content',
        component: Content,
        children: [
            {
                name: "lojas",
                path: '/Lojas',
                component: lojas
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usa [um dos métodos que o `vue-router` implementa](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) no componente, o `beforeRouteEnter`.

Esses `hooks`/ ganchos pré defenidos como o `beforeRouteEnter` são chamados antes da rota ser rederizada, e neste caso passanto uma função à callback `next` essa função é chamada quando o componente tiver sido instanciado e fica disponível dentro dessa função.
Nesse momento podes chamar os métodos da função.

Exemplo:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    dataItem: [],
    errors: []
  }),
  methods: {
    atualizarLoja() {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8090/API/Lojas`)
        .then(response => {
          this.dataItem = response.data.Data
          $('#dataTable').DataTable(datatableConfigBR)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
        })
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => vm.atualizarLoja())
  }
}
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/Ly4eaeyq/**

Se queres forçar o update do componente estando já na view desse componente o router não te ajuda. Se não há navegação o router não faz nada.

Nesse caso a melhor possibilidade é criar um botão de update, ou mudar o botão de click no menu para um componente que chama o método.

Essa ultima ideia seria assim: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/Ly4eaeyq/1/

Comment: Sergio, fiquei na duvida de como funciona esse codigo, poderia explicar? sempre aprendendo com você rs

Comment: @RafaelAugusto editei a rersposta com um exemplo. A minha resposta inicial seguia [uma resposta](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-beforeenter-access-vue-apps-methods/4056/3) de um dos core-developers mas que não consegui implementar, acho que seria da versão `1.x`. Agora corrigi e dei um exemplo. Obrigado pelo pedido de explicações, assim corrigi a minha resposta :)

Comment: @Sergio entendi o que fez! mas caio no mesmo problema que o exemplo do Rafael, A chamada da Axios API está no **Lojas.vue**, e este Method de Click teria que ficar no meu **Menu.vue**. Como faço nesse problema? Obrigado!!

Comment: @Jackson esse método que atualiza a loja é chamado sempre que abres essa página. Não é isso que queres?

Comment: Sim, ele já funciona na propriedade Created(). Eu queria chamar de novo o method do axios quando eu clicar na página do menu. Como se fosse um Refresh da página. É como se eu estivesse no Lojas.vue, e fosse no Menu e clicasse no "Lojas" para trazer os dados. Hoje eu tenho que ir para outra view, e voltar para "Lojas" para o Axios dar o Get de novo

Comment: @Jackson ok. Editei a resposta. Dá uma olhada e testa o segundo jsFiddle

Comment: Entendi @Sergio! Obrigado pela ajuda. Foi bem claro =)

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa recarregar o `view`, basta ter um `method` e chama-lo sempre que clicar, ou mesmo, recarrega-lo em x minutos. Ex:

```
<script>
   export default{
      data(){
         return{
            dados: []
         }
      },
      methods: {
         api(){
            axios.get('URL')
            .then(response => {
                this.dados = response.data
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('ERRO')
            })
         }
      }

   }
</script>
```

e ai em um link `<button @click="api">Atualizar</button>`

Ou mesmo em `X` tempo

```
<script>
   export default{
      data(){
         return{
            dados: []
         }
      },
      created(){
          this.api()
      },
      methods: {
         api(){
            setInterval(function(){
            axios.get('URL')
            .then(response => {
                this.dados = response.data
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('ERRO')
            })
            }, 1000)
         }
      }

   }
</script>
```

Comment: Gostei muito da sua alternativa, mas o problema é que a chamada da Axios API está no **Lojas.vue**, e este Method de Click teria que ficar no meu **Menu.vue**.